# Flutter - CircleAvatar with dynamic radius according to available space

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like the CircleAvatar to take a specific percentage (e.g. 50%) of the available space instead of specifying a fixed radius. How would you approach that?

Comment: available space of what ?, paste the code

Comment: Available room to grow into, e.g. unoccupied space in a container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure this is the best solution.

You can use `LayoutBuilder` to get the max constraints then build according to it.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            height: 100.0,
            width: 100.0,
            child: _buildCircleAvatar(),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            height: 300.0,
            width: 300.0,
            child: _buildCircleAvatar(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCircleAvatar() {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final radius = min(constraints.maxHeight / 4, constraints.maxWidth / 4);
        return Center(
          child: CircleAvatar(
            radius: radius,
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
              "https://as.ftcdn.net/r/v1/pics/7b11b8176a3611dbfb25406156a6ef50cd3a5009/home/discover_collections/optimized/image-2019-10-11-11-36-27-681.jpg",
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for a more plain solutin than using LayoutBuilder, though I guess it's always possible to use it to get constraints as last resort :)

Answer (score -1):

```
                   Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2 ,
                    child:CircleAvatar(),
                      )
```

you can use this to get the responsive avatar

Comment: I don't believe CircleAvatar expands to fit its Container. I also just tested it. Are you sure about this?